# Execute SQL Server Pass-Through Query From Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, pass-through

I have an `UPDATE` pass through query saved in Access 2007. When I double-click on the pass through query it runs successfully. How can I get this query to run from VBA? I'd like it to run when my "splash screen" loads.

I'm currently using the following code:

`CurrentDb.Execute "Q_UPDATE_PASSTHROUGH", dbSQLPassThrough`

But I get the following message:

[image]

The pass-through query contains all the connection information and I've confirmed the SQL syntax is correct by running it multiple times, so not sure what I'm missing in my VBA call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the QueryDef's `Execute` method:

```vb
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Q_UPDATE_PASSTHROUGH").Execute
```

I don't think you should need to explicitly include the *dbSQLPassThrough* option here, but you can try like this if you want it:

```vb
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Q_UPDATE_PASSTHROUGH").Execute dbSQLPassThrough
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into the same problem. While the above mentioned `Execute` method is working for most cases, some people (me included) experiencing a `Run-time error '3001': Invalid Argument` when using the parameter *dbSQLPassThrough*. This was also addressed in the answer above me and happens even in the simplest SQL-statements.

For those who are having the same problem, I recommend using the `OpenQuery` method as alternative.

A valid substitution for the following code

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Q_UPDATE_PASSTHROUGH").Execute
```

would be

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q_UPDATE_PASSTHROUGH"
```

I know this thread is 4 years old, however, searching for a solution for the not working `Execute` method on Google brings you directly to this thread which is why I thought it would be useful to add an alternative solution which solved this problem for me.

Comment: *experiencing a Run-time error '3001': Invalid Argument when using the parameter dbSQLPassThrough.* -- Does it also not work if you omit the parameter dbSQLPassThrough?

Comment: The `Execute` statement works if I omit the _dbSQLPassThrough_ parameter, but from my still very limited understanding of Access VBA I thought it is necessary to use it because otherwise the heavy SQL-statement be executed on my local machine instead on the SQL Server.

Comment: No. If you `.Execute` a saved query that is a PT query (i.e. has a Connect string), you don't need the parameter - Access knows it's a PT query and will not try to run it with the Access DB engine. In most cases it wouldn't work anyway, since the SQL dialects are different between Access and the server DB.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the QueryDef's `Execute` method is the recommended way to achieve your goal.

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Q_UPDATE_PASSTHROUGH").Execute
```

However, I can point out that in a similar case with Access 2010, using `dbSQLPassThrough` for the `Options` parameter caused a `Run-time error '3001': Invalid Argument`.